# React: appendChild alternative when using React.createElement

Tags: reactjs

```
this.cliponSwatchesContainer.current.append(
          React.createElement(
            'button',
            {
              id: colorSwatches[cliponSwatch],
              className: this.state.swatchClassName,
              onClick: (e) => this.setFrame(e, colorSwatches),
              ref: this.swatch,
            },
            React.createElement(
              'img',
              { src: this.state.swatchImgSrc, alt: this.state.swatchImgAlt },
              null
            )
          )
        );
```

I'm trying to convert a `document.createElement` to `React.createElement`. And when I'm using `appendChild()`, I'm getting the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.

So, I tried using `append()` and the error is gone but now the UI shows:

> [object Object][object Object]

Comment: You don't need `appendChild` or `append` in React beyond the root app node. It does all the DOM manipulation for you. Create a functional component and return the JSX or `React.createElement` objects (or define a class component with a `render` function) to render them. What are you trying to achieve here and can you share a [mcve]? Thanks.

Comment: @ggorlen I'm integrating a vanillaJS project to reactJS. So I'm changing doc.createElement to React.createElement. It's a huge code base so sharing a minimal reproducible example is feasible. But the gist is that I'm trying to dynamically generate IMG buttons. I know how to do it in full on react but this project is only integration not full conversion to react

Comment: The problem is that `React.createElement` is not really analogous to `document.createElement` because the things they create are extremely different.
 
React elements are React's representation of a tree of DOM elements, but they do not behave like DOM elements. You can't manipulate them like you would a DOM element. Their only use is as the return value of component render methods.